# Two vertices with shortest path

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to solve this question but got stuck.
Need some help,Thanks.

**Given an undirected Connected graph G with non-negative values at edges.

Let A be a subgroup of V(G), where V(G) is the group of vertices  in G.**

**-Find a pair of vertices (a,b) that belongs to A, such that the weight of the shortest path between them in G is minimal, in O(V*(E+Vlog(v)))**

I got the idea of using Dijkstra's algorithm in each node which will give me O(V*(E+Vlog(v))). I think that's too much and we can do it by using Dijkstra's one time.
So thought about connecting the vertices in A somehow,did'nt find any useful way.

Comment: Share your findings. Where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: Edited the question @MrSmith42

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Two vertices with lowest path weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037215/find-two-vertices-with-lowest-path-weight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's understand the above scenario by looking at an example.

Let graph `G` comprise of - `a, b, c, d, e, f` i.e

```
V(G) = {a,b,c,d,e,f}
```

Now As said A is a subgroup of V(G), so let's assume

```
A = {a,b,c}
```

Now run `Floyd–Warshall algorithm` over this graph and that will basically provide you with shortest paths between all pairs of vertices.

And the overall time complexity of this algorithm is O(V^3) where V is the number of vertices in the graph.

Once this algorithm is complete you can easily check which two pairs of vertices are present in the subgroup A.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help,thanks.But I was told that it can be done in - O((E+V)log(v)))

Comment: @Omarkhateeb then why don't you directly ask that person who told you that it could be done in O((E+V)log(v)) time....

Comment: Also if you find the solution in that time please let us know too by updating your question. Also if my answer helps in any way you can mark it :)