# Find Two vertices with lowest path weight

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I am trying to solve this question but got stuck.
Need some help,Thanks.

**Given an undirected Connected graph G with non-negative values at edges.

Let A be a subgroup of V(G), where V(G) is the group of vertices  in G.**

**-Find a pair of vertices (a,b) that belongs to A, such that the weight of the shortest path between them in G is minimal, in O((E+V)*log(v)))**

I got the idea of using Dijkstra's algorithm in each node which will give me O(V*((E+V)logv))),which is too much.
So thought about connecting the vertices in A somehow,did'nt find any useful way.
Also tried changing the way Dijkstra's algorithm work,But it get's to hard to prove with no improvment in time complexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if the optimal pair is `(a, b)`, then from every node `u` in the optimal path, `a` and `b` are the closest two nodes in `A`.

I believe we should extend Dijkstra's algorithm in the following manners:

1. Start with all nodes in `A`, instead of a single `source_node`.
2. For each node, don't just remember the `shortest_distance` and the `previous_node`, but also the `closest_source_node` to remember which node in `A` gave the shortest distance.
3. Also, for each node, remember the `second_shortest_distance`, the `second_closest_source_node`, and `previous_for_second_closest_source_node` (shorter name suggestions are welcome). Make sure that `second_closest_source_node` is never the `closest_source_node`. Also, think carefully about how you update these variables, the optimal path for a node can become part of the second best path for it's neighbour.
4. Visit the entire graph, don't just stop at the first node whose `closest_source` and `second_closest_source` are found.
5. Once the entire graph is covered, search for the node whose `shortest_distance + second_shortest_distance` is smallest.

Comment: But instead of starting Dijkstra's  with each node from A,we can connect them to node S with edges equal 0.that make's it easier to prove.